# Change background color in cell depending on another cell value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to make it so that depending on the number in one cell it will change the color in another cell. But I need it so that it will do more than two colors.

```
If M4 said 0-4 it would then make I4 red,  
if M4 was between 5-19 I4 would be yellow,  
if M4 was between 20-29 I4 would be orange,  
if M4 was 30+ it would make I4 green.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please select I4 and with Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if..., **Custom formula is** enter:

```
=M4>29
```

and for Formatting style choose green fill, <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Then with **Add another rule** in this order repeat as below:

```
=M4>19 orange  
=M4>4  yellow
=M4>=0 red
```